# Wrap table cells around the corner to be on the same line with a table row with uneven cells from another table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have two tables with two columns each –  on every `tr` two `td` elements. Assuming the last `tr` of the first table has only one `td` element, there will be a blank space at the end. You could solve this problem with `colspan="2"`. However, the goal is to have the first cell of the next table to be on line with the last cell of the first table.

To illustrate it using a snippet: I want *Table 2, Cell 1* to be **on the same line** as *Table 1, Cell 3*.

```css
#container{
  width: 160px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: blue;
  zoom: 3.5; /* better visibility */
}

td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#table-2{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="table-1">
    <tr>
      <td>Table 1, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Table 1, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Table 1, Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
  <table id="table-2">
    <tr>
      <td>Table 2, Cell 1</td>
      <td>Table 2, Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really do want two tables, if you move Table 2, Cell 1 into Table 1, then it is no longer part of Table 2.

The only way to do what you are asking is to:

1. Manually put Table 2, Cell 1 in table 1 within the HTML (and continue the pattern from there; your decision as to whether you really want two tables or jus tone big table), or
2. Dynamically generate your table using a server-side framework (e.g. MVC, MVVM, PHP, JSP, etc.) to ensure that every column is filled, regardless of the table it is in.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be two tables. But I already have a different design solution in mind. Was just curious if this would work – thanks for you help!